# "ValueError: bad transparency mask" when pasting one image onto another with Python Imaging Library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to paste an image onto a backgorund with Python Imaging Library like this:

```
card = Image.new("RGB", (220, 220), (255, 255, 255))
img = Image.open("/Users/paulvorobyev/test.png")

...

x, y = img.size
card.paste(img, (0, 0, x, y), img)

card.save("test.png")
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
 "ValueError: bad transparency mask"
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does `card.paste(img, (0, 0, x, y))` work? (i.e. without a transparency mask)

Comment: Daniel: Omitting a transparency doesn't cause the program to crash, but the colors look weird and the image has a somewhat "grainy" quality.

Comment: Just realized that the color error was due to something else (didn't set bg image as RGBA). Pasting without a transparency mask does, in fact, work as intended. Thank you :)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Late to the game here, but I just ran into the same issue. After some googling I was able to get my mask to work by making sure all of the images being used were the same mode (specifically "RGBA").

You might try this:

```
card = Image.new("RGBA", (220, 220), (255, 255, 255))
img = Image.open("/Users/paulvorobyev/test.png").convert("RGBA")
x, y = img.size
card.paste(img, (0, 0, x, y), img)
card.save("test.png", format="png")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that set me along the right lines. In my experience though, it's only the mask that needs to be RGBA, base images are better in RGB.

Comment: That seems to be a matter of opinion @Docbrisky. You got some documentation to support your statement?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be right, only the mask needs to be RGBA.