# Bad transparency mask only when using IF statement?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The .paste here was working fine, until I used it within an IF statement. I'm not sure why that would trigger an issue with transparency mask.

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image

file_list = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\blake\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Right Click Save Images")

for x in file_list: 

    ran_num = random.randint(0,100)

    background = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Right Click Save Images\\" + (x))
    background= background.resize((631,631),Image.ANTIALIAS)

    if ran_num < 70:
        foreground = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\OneDrive\\Pictures\\savetest.png")
        background.paste(foreground, (380,460), foreground)
        #print("Save")
        
    
    elif ran_num < 80:
        foreground = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\OneDrive\\Pictures\\diskerrortest.png")
        background.paste(foreground, (380,460), foreground)
        #print("Disk Error")

    elif ran_num < 90:
        foreground = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\OneDrive\\Pictures\\upsidedown.png")
        background.paste(foreground, (380,460), foreground)
        #print("upsidedown")  
    
    
    background.save("rightClick"+ (x) +".png")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\blake\Right Click Save Program\import random.py", line 16, in <module>
    background.paste(foreground, (380,460), foreground)
  File "C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1557, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)
ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ValueError: bad transparency mask" when pasting one image onto another with Python Imaging Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273592/valueerror-bad-transparency-mask-when-pasting-one-image-onto-another-with-pyt)

Comment: What is `line 16`? What happens if you remove the `if...else` chain and just include that line?

Comment: Side note, you should give your file a more meaningful name and avoid using spaces in file names.

Comment: It can't be related to the `if` statement. It's almost certainly due to the file that the `if` statement is selecting as `foreground`.