# ValueError: bad transparency mask

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

2 years ago i programmed a fun litte program which makes automated collages from random jpgs, colors them and makes some random effects.

i used it occasionally to generate jpgs.

today when i wanted to use it after a long time i experience an error which was not there before, so i suppose it must have come with some python or module update?
it happens to this line:

```
older.paste(result, (0, 0), mask=result)
```

and the error is:

```
line 1582, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)
ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

so it seems paste does not accept the value.

i'm using Image, ImageDraw from PIL

any hints where i should look closer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273592/valueerror-bad-transparency-mask-when-pasting-one-image-onto-another-with-pyt    does this answer your question?

Comment: Please show a minimal, complete, runnable version of your code that causes the error so we can help you properly. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273592/valueerror-bad-transparency-mask-when-pasting-one-image-onto-another-with-pyt solved the problem. i converted mask and source to RGBA and the error was gone. thanks. i'm still wondering why this problem occured after hundreds of error free runs.